# Handlebar #each with some other attributes

Tags: javascript, http, handlebars.js

I have a special problem with Handlebar's #each loop.

I have a hbs file, called: list.hbs. In the inside, looks like this:

```
{{#each subjects}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{subject_name}}</td>
        <td>{{subject_code}}</td>
        <td>{{subject_size}}</td>
        <td>{{subject_location}}</td>
        <td>{{subject_teacher}}</td>
        <td>
        {{testString}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
{{testString}}
```

when i reach my endpoint, i use this line in my javascript file:

```
 res.render('subjects/list', {
                subjects: __subjects ,
                testString: "some text for example",
            });
```

The problem is this: when the Handlebar is doing the for_each function, it ignoring the testString attribute. When it's done, and quit from each, it can print in the HTML the test string. 
I know i could write this testString in my subject object, but this is just a representation of my problem, i have more complicated structure than this.
Some idea, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help finally, the answer is this:

```
    {{#each subjects}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{subject_name}}</td>
        <td>{{subject_code}}</td>
        <td>{{subject_size}}</td>
        <td>{{subject_location}}</td>
        <td>{{subject_teacher}}</td>
        <td>
        {{../testString}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
{{testString}}
```